# Is it possible to use hardware acceleration in OpenCL

Tags: opengl, gpu, gpgpu, opencl

I built a small game engine using OpenCL and SDL2 but it's not running really fast compare to Vulkan and OpenGL. I wrote rasterization code, but when I did some research Vulkan and OpenGL use hardware base rasterization and my rasterization is software base, so my code will be a lot slower. Is it possible to force OpenCL to enable hardware base rasterization?

Comment: If you've determined that Vulkan and OpenGL implementations are faster at doing what they're designed to do — rasterization — than an API designed to do GPU workloads that are *not* rasterization, why not simply implement your rastization workloads in Vulkan/OpenGL or other graphics APIs (ie. what the rest of the games industry does)? Do you have some special requirement that demands the use of OpenCL for this task?

Comment: Because I already have experience with opencl and learning Vulkan and OpenGL is kind annoying, plus I want totally control of my code

Comment: In what sense do you believe using these APIs would take away control of your code?

Comment: I would like to implement my own 3d math library, as I could have more control then using GLM library

Comment: You don't have to use GLM with OpenGL, so you can use your own 3D math library with OpenGL, or any other graphics API. I get a strong impression from reading your questions that you are labouring under some serious misconceptions about what these graphics APIs are and how they work. I think you would benefit from building at least a small sample with one, to learn how it actually works in practice.

Comment: why do you want to rasterize using OpenCL, when OpenGL (and Vulkan)'s purpose IS to rasterize?